# $\dim \operatorname{Hom}_{S_n}(\mathbb C [X_l], \mathbb C [X_k])$ is equal to the number of double cosets $P_l \backslash S_n/P_k$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, symmetric-groups

I have the following problem:

$S_n$ is acting on the set of $k$ element subsets of $\{1,...,n\}$ ($X_k$). Show that $\dim\operatorname{Hom}_{S_n}(\mathbb C [X_l], \mathbb C [X_k])$ is equal to the number of double cosets $P_l \backslash S_n/P_k$, $1\leq l \leq k \leq n$, where $P_i$ is the stabilizer of $\{1,...,i\}$

I’m asking for any hints. Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what $\mathbb{C}[X_\ell]$ means. Is it a polynomial ring where you've adjoined a variable for each $k$-element subset of $\{1, \ldots, n\}$?

Comment: @hunter It is set of functions from $X_k$ to $\mathbb C$

Comment: This is true more generally for homs between permutation representations $G/H, G/K$.